# Definir valor padrão para uma string em um projeto mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Possuo um projeto MVC onde gostaria de deixar um valor padrão em uma Action, acredito que minha tentativa esteja errada:

a model seria o status e o valor deveria ser "aguardando", porém mesmo assim não consigo sucesso

rEQ_ACESSO.Status = "Aguardando"

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID_COLAB,NOME_COLAB,PNOME,Status,sNOME,
DEPTO_PRINCIPAL,NOME_DEPART,CARGO_COLAB,NOME_USUARIO,TIPO_EMAIL,CRACHA,ATIVO,UNIDADE,GESTOR,
ACESSO,MOTIVO_CONTRATACAO,CLT,TERCEIROS,CEL,COMPUTADOR,DATA_INICIO,CRIADO_POR,DATA_CRIACAO,
ALTERADO_POR,DATA_ALTERACAO,EMAIL_ALTERACAO")] REQ_ACESSO rEQ_ACESSO)
        {          
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                rEQ_ACESSO.Status = "Aguardando";
                rEQ_ACESSO.ID_COLAB = Guid.NewGuid();
                db.REQ_ACESSO.Add(rEQ_ACESSO);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(rEQ_ACESSO);
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer isso, acho interessante você adicionar o `default` diretamente na sua `Model`.

Aqui tem um [exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31749017/8469314) para te ajudar.

Na qual você pode fazer algo do tipo:

```
public class MinhaModel {
    public string CampoSemDefault { get; set; }
    public string CampoComDefault { get; set; } = "Alguma coisa aqui";
}
```

[Aqui](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/set-default-value-to-property-in-csharp) tem mais aluns exemplos.

Comment: Deu certinho, muito obrigado!

Comment: Show, marca a resposta como aceita, para assim poder ajudar as outras pessoas.